# How to delete data from room database inside a broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-room, android-database

In my app, I have a broadcast receiver that send notifications. I want to delete a specific object from the database after the notification is sent. In my activities, I used a viewModel instance to delete data, but a viewModel instance cannot be created inside a broadcast receiver or a work manager. Is there anything that can be done to delete data from a broadcast receiver while using room database.

This is how I created a viewModel instance in my activities:

```
private val taskViewModel: TaskViewModel by viewModels {
    TaskViewModelFactory((application as TaskApplication).repository)
}
```

I am getting a syntax error when I try to create a viewModel instance like that in my receiver or in a workManager.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the object from the DAO using Thread without ViewModel

```
class Receiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val id = intent!!.getIntExtra("id_key", 0)
        Thread {
            AppDatabase.getInstance(context).appDao().deleteObject(id)
        }.start()
    }
}
```

Comment: Working Answer,